Entity Framework - multiple column foreign key
I have a "notes" table which can be related to several other tables - in simple terms it is :
NoteId (int),
PrimaryKeyType (int),
PrimaryKeyId (int),
NoteText (varchar(max))
I then have several other tables such as Customer / Lead / Contact - each has it's own PK i.e. CustomerId, LeadId, ContactId.
When I write records into the Notes table I of course insert the PK of the parent record into the PrimaryKeyValue, and a constant value for each parent table in the PrimaryKeyType field - e.g Customer = 1, Lead = 2, Contact = 3.
This works fine and I can have a single set of code to retrieve the related Notes records, just passing in the type ID, and the actual PK.
My question is this - when I want to declare a navigation property in my Notes class so I can get to the name of the Customer / Lead / Contact how do I do that in this scenario - say for example I want to display a table of all recently added notes, one of the columns being the source of that name (Customer / Lead / Contact name).
I can see I need a multi column FK on both PrimaryKeyType and PrimaryKeyId, just not sure how to implement that in this scenario?
